# Using strategy or additional class?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have following code example (code below).

I have interfaces `OnlyReverse` and `OnlySplit` which define operations on class `Data`. I will sometimes have class available only for reversing and sometimes, I will be able to do reversing and splitting.

In the code I have 2 approaches.

1st approach is to use 2 separate classes for these 2 separate use-cases `ReverseAndSplitImpl` and `OnlyReverseImpl`. Here I do not like that I need additional class, and that I need to duplicate some of the code between those 2 classes.

2nd approach is to use 1 class for both use-cases `SingleClassForReverseAndSplitImpl` and then use strategy to inject either `NormalSplit` or `NoSplit`. Here I do not like this additional `NoSplit` class that is basically artificial one.

According to interface segregation principle - do I need to have `ReverseAndSplit` joining interface, or should I always use both interfaces separately (like `SingleClassForReverseAndSplitImpl implements OnlyReverse, OnlySplit` and not `SingleClassForReverseAndSplitImpl implements ReverseAndSplit`)?

Which approach of these is better in a long run (more flexible in the future)?

```
class Data{
  String a;
}

interface OnlyReverse{
  Data getData();
  OnlyReverse reverse();
}

interface OnlySplit{
  OnlySplit split();
}

interface ReverseAndSplit extends OnlyReverse, OnlySplit{
  @Override
  ReverseAndSplit reverse();
  @Override
  ReverseAndSplit split();
}

//------------------------- USE DISTINCT CLASSES; ONE HAS SPLIT OTHER NO

class ReverseAndSplitImpl implements ReverseAndSplit{
  Data data;

  public ReverseAndSplitImpl(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  @Override
  public Data getData() {
    return data;
  }

  @Override
  public ReverseAndSplit reverse() {
    //here reverse and return
    return new ReverseAndSplitImpl(data);
  }

  @Override
  public ReverseAndSplit split() {
    //here split and return
    return new ReverseAndSplitImpl(data);
  }
}

class OnlyReverseImpl implements OnlyReverse{
  Data data;

  public OnlyReverseImpl(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  @Override
  public Data getData() {
    return data;
  }

  @Override
  public OnlyReverse reverse() {
    return new OnlyReverseImpl(data);
  }
}

//------------------------- USE DISTINCT CLASSES; ONE HAS SPLIT OTHER NO

//------------------------- USE STRATEGY TO CHOOSE TO HAVE SPLITTING OR NO
interface SplitStrategy{
  Data split(Data data);
}
class NormalSplit implements SplitStrategy{
  @Override
  public Data split(Data data) {
    return new Data();
  }
}
//NullObject pattern
class NoSplit implements SplitStrategy{
  @Override
  public Data split(Data data) {
    return data;
  }
}

class SingleClassForReverseAndSplitImpl implements ReverseAndSplit{
  Data data;
  SplitStrategy splitStrategy;

  public SingleClassForReverseAndSplitImpl(Data data, SplitStrategy splitStrategy) {
    this.data = data;
    this.splitStrategy = splitStrategy;
  }

  @Override
  public Data getData() {
    return data;
  }

  @Override
  public ReverseAndSplit reverse() {
    //here reverse and return
    return new SingleClassForReverseAndSplitImpl(data, splitStrategy);
  }

  @Override
  public ReverseAndSplit split() {
    //here split and return
    SingleClassForReverseAndSplitImpl s = new SingleClassForReverseAndSplitImpl(data, splitStrategy);
    s.data = splitStrategy.split(data);
    return s;
  }
}
//------------------------- USE STRATEGY TO CHOOSE TO HAVE SPLITTING OR NO

public class Decorator {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReverseAndSplit s11 = new SingleClassForReverseAndSplitImpl(new Data(), new NoSplit());
    s11 = s11.reverse();
    s11 = s11.split();  //has split operation, but NoSplit will do nothing

    OnlyReverse s12 = new OnlyReverseImpl(new Data());
    s12 = s12.reverse();
    //has no split operation present

    //Going from NoSplit to SplitAndReverse
    ReverseAndSplit s21 = new SingleClassForReverseAndSplitImpl(s11.getData(), new NormalSplit());
    s21 = s21.reverse();
    s21 = s21.split();  //has split and now it is using NormalSplit

    ReverseAndSplit s22 = new ReverseAndSplitImpl(s12.getData());
    s22 = s22.reverse();
    s22 = s22.split();

  }
}
```

Comment: Providing the alternative / `ReverseAndSplit` isn't necessarily a _bad_ thing, what is bad is making your code dependant on those more concrete interfaces. For implementation purposes, it's usually easier to aggregate and utilize a single interface

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's reasonable to use your first approach (two simpler interfaces) but to not call them `OnlyReverse` and `OnlySplit` but `Reverse` and `Split`. So it's reasonable to combine them and in future you can also just use one of them.

But it's also depending on your domain objects, so it's hard to make a choice for you. But I would not create an interface called `NoSplit` because you could still implement `ReverseAndSplit` *and* `NoSplit` which would make no sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Interface Segregation Principle, if you have a client who *never* splits, then you should not present that client with an interface including a `split` method. The Strategy / Null Object approach is suitable for a single client who sometimes requires splitting and other times does not. The separate interfaces approach is suitable for two different clients who have different requirements.

Comment: `split` is additional functionality that can be executed on internal data (or not if strategy set to null object). everything else regarding logic should remain the same. I guess it is then single client approach...

Comment: Basically, by using this approach, I want to prevent some of `SingleClassForReverseAndSplitImpl` to do `split` and for some others to allow it - e.g. based on `Data` that I initialize it with. If data is set to "1", "2", "3" - then allow `split`, otherwise use `NoSplit`.

Comment: @MarkoKraljevic How would the client know whether they can call split or not? How would they handle not being able to split/reverse? It's not clear how clients will be using these classes & interfaces.

Comment: @plalx I guess they will not. Since I can have logic to to initialize strategy inside my class, but method split() will always be there. Just sometimes it will do nothing if called. Is there some better approach like 1st one, but not to duplicate same code? Like delegate all same methods to parent, and have only single split() handled inside. But then - how to access `Data` in delegated class?

Comment: @MarkoKraljevic How would you feel about calling "string".split() and having it do nothing? Will clients be writing algorithms to manipulate the data? If we dont know how clients are going to use those interfaces & classes we can't help in the design.

Comment: @plalx GUI will render all objects from `List< ReverseAndSplit> myList`, and those that support splitting will have button split next to it. Then when user clicks split REST request is sent and called doSomeSplitting(id) and then in the code there will be only `myList.getByData(id)` -> so whatever is returned here will definitely support splitting and can use `returnedFromGetByData.split()`.

Comment: @MarkoKraljevic In this case you can choose whether to use `instanceof Splitable`, etc. to check if the feature is supported, hold 2 separate lists (Reversable, Splitable), or go for the strategy pattern which somewhats makes sense in your context b/c the client expects it to not do anything if not supported.